# How to calculate the frequency of a signal without knowing the sampling frequency using Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency

I have a signal and I am using Matlab command pwelch to calculate the frequency of the signal, but the frequency I obtained is changed as I changed the sampling frequency.

For example, when using sampling frequency equal 8000, the frequency appear to be 1 Khz, while when I use 16000 sampling frequency the frequency of the signal appear to be 2 Khz.

which is the correct frequency? and is there other method to calculate the frequency of a signal without prior knowledge of the sampling frequency?

Comment: Simply put you can't.  You don't know whether the frequency components are a result of aliasing or are a true representation of the components at sampling frequency you're looking at.  I'm sorry to say that you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).

Comment: can you show your matlab code?  you can use a relative high sampling rate to avoid aliasing in frequency domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simple example, calculate the frequency for this signal:

[0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 -1]

From such a signal you can only know that you frequency is 1/4*samplerate. Without the sample rate you can't calculate the frequency.